# Search all numbers

Tags: regex, search, vim, numbers

I want to highlight all numbers (not single digits!) in VIM:

- all numbers (wherever in document) with/without "." or ","
- all numbers (wherever in document) with negative value

p.e.

```
8.20  
8,500
-2.40  
28.000.000  
1000,2 etc
```

The "." or "," has to be included in the highlight if within a number.
1, or 1. --> has to highlight only the "1"
Also the negative numbers has to be highlighted (including "-") but not when there is another digit before the "-".

p.e. -5-6-7-8-9-10
has to highlight -5,6,7,8,9,10

A negative number has to be seen as a negative number and not as a negative and positive number  p.e. "-5" has to be highlighted as "-5" and not as "-5" and "5"
The reason is that I copy all matches and don't want to find two matches where there is only number ("-5")

"--5" has to be highlighted as a positive value "5"

I've created this regex:

```
\%(\d\)\@<![-]*\d\{1,}\([.,]\d\+\)*
```

but it highlights negative numbers two times (as negative number and as number without the "-")

Comment: There's not value in doing `[-]` instead of `-`. It's a single atom either way. As for the `*` that follows, you do want `---1` to be highlighted?

Comment: Chris, in the above example -5-6-7-8-9-10 it has to highight -5,6,7,8,9,10 but not the dot before 6,7,8,9,10. "---1" has not te be highlighted a negative value but as "1".

Comment: Then the `[-]*` should be `-\?` instead.

Comment: `-?` --> pattern not found. And `-\?`--> highlights one `-` in `--\d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\%([0-9-]\@<!-\)\?\d[0-9,.]*`

Pretty weird requirements, i think that's everything you mentioned, but not sure about your '--5' stipulation - does that mean you want an even number of '-' characters to not match? This doesn't do that.

EDIT: Updated to disallow multiple `-` characters before the number. Not sure if that's truly what you want - consider `---5` for example.

Comment: As you've indicated it does select all "-" before digits. Not exactly what I want.

Comment: So what exactly do you want? Even number of '-' not to match? Just 2?

Comment: please see my first message. More then one "-" before a number is a positive number. A number is a negative number only when there is one "-" before the number and no digits before the "-". (I hope I made myself clear now :))

Comment: Thank you Tom. Do you know what would be the regex if also `\a-` (a letter before the "-") will make it a positive number?

Comment: found it :-) Thank you very much for your regex.